# CSS --variable for Sass colors

Tags: css, variables, sass

I'm trying to use CSS variables --variable with some Sass function such as rgba or a color mix but I'm keeping getting the error:

**"Error: $color: "var(--color)" is not a color for `rgba'"**

This is my code:

```
--color: #{rgb(132, 200, 3)};
--rgba: #{rgba(var(--color), 0.5)};

.color {
  color: mix($white, var(--rgba), 50%);
}
```

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  --color: #{rgb(132, 200, 3)};
  --rgba: #{rgba(var(-red), 0.5)};

.color {
  color: mix($white, var(--rgba), 50%);
}
```

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Comment: Keep on getting Error: $color: "var(--color)" is not a color for `rgba'

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591465/use-css-variables-with-rgba-for-gradient-transparency) @FilipVanReeth