# gulp-sass rgba must be a color

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am using gulp-sass and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color
```

When I am trying to compile the following code:

```
color: rgba(var(--color), 1)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use CSS variables with rgba for gradient transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591465/use-css-variables-with-rgba-for-gradient-transparency)

Answer (score -1):

Try this SASS:

```
$r: 255
$g: 0
$b: 0
$a: 1

color: rgba($r,$g,$b,$a)
```

Compiles to this CSS:

```
color: red;
```

If you'd like to stick to CSS4 variables, you can find out more about handling this issue [here](https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass).

Alternatively, see the answer on [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591465/use-css-variables-with-rgba-for-gradient-transparency).